# Loosing session when redirecting to home page from login page in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, express, server-side

This are middlewares and their options i used:

```
app.use(require('cookie-parser')(credentials.cookieSecret));
app.use(require('express-session')({
    secret: 'introduced skill',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {secure:true,maxAge:900000}
}));
```

This my post login function :

```
app.post('/login',function(req,res){    
    req.session.email=req.body.u_email;
    res.redirect('/admin');
});
```

This is my code for redirecting to home page after successful login.
I am saving session using email .

When user is redirecting to home page i am loosing the session.
Actual problem is `req` object in the above code is not the same object which is in routing function .
I didn't understand how new `req` object is creating instead of using old `req` object.
Please help me with the problem.

I am using express 4 ,express-session

Comment: A more complete code snippet would be helpful, so we could see how your middleware and routes are defined.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
req.session.email=req.body.u_email;
console.log(req.session);
req.session.save(function(err){
  if (err !== null) {
    next(err);
  } else {
    res.redirect('/');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed value of **secure in cookie to default** then it works.
I didn't understand why it wasn't work before.
Can any one explain about it.

Comment: Are you accessing your page using `https`?

Comment: I got it works for only https . I go through the documentation again.Thanks @t.niese

Comment: Thats what `secure` is about ;)

Comment: How can we provide utmost security by using http connection? @t.niese